# How to add a markdown editor in React which can support math equations?

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I found some available markdown packages for React but unfortunately, all of them cant support math equation.

So I wonder if there is any open source package which can enable user to write and display markdown in React, and **write math equations**?

Comment: did you find any package ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a react markdown editors with math support

- https://uiwjs.github.io/react-md-editor/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathpix-markdown-it

Here is a Javascript library and it looks like Very High-Quality math work. I think it can be very helpful. Check the live demo here

- https://www.mathjax.org/#demo
- https://cnpmjs.org/browse/keyword/mathjax (List of mathjax components)

Here is mathjax react component

- https://cnpmjs.org/package/mathjax-react

This editor can generate math markdown code.

- https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

The point to note here is, you will have to write the special code format **(ax^2 + bx + c = 0)** yourself to display math equation and formulas. I couldn't find the editor like, you click on the formula and your text automatically embed the required math coding and display the final result. You will have to write code according to your requirements.

I hope this will be helpful for you.